# Get the variable value if variable name is stored as string in Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am completely new to Groovy and Jenkins. I have some pre defined variable in Groovy Script (of Jenkins pipeline) and need to pick any one variable from them dynamically based on job/user input.
The example context of requirement is as provided below.
Here variable env is my input and based on that I should get correct userid.

```
env = "dev" //Input
def stg_userid = "abc"
def dev_userid = "xyz"
uid_var_name = "${env}_userid"
print "${uid_var_name}" // It is giving "dev_userid"
```

print 'abc' if we give 'stg' for env ;
print 'xyz' if we give 'dev' for env

Tried searching online for dynamic variable name use case in Groovy , but didn't got anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

usually it's question of complex variable (Map) that holds parameters for all possible environments

and you could get section of this configuration by environment name

```js
env = "dev"
def config = [
  dev: [
    user: 'aaa',
    url: 'aaa-url'
  ],
  stg: [
    user: 'zzz',
    url: 'zzz-url'
  ]
]

def uid_var_name = config[env].user  // returns "aaa"
```